# Scala converters convert Java collections to Wrapper objects

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections

I have a scala function which returns a `util.Map[String], util.Set[String]`.

```
def getAcls(): Map[String, Set[String]] = {
((for (groupRole: GroupRoleAccess <- groupRoleAccess;
     user <- groupService.getGroup(groupRole.groupId).getUsers;
     permissions = roleService.getRole(groupRole.roleId)  .getPermissions)
  yield user.getUserId -> permissions).groupBy(_._1).map { case (k,v) => (k, v.flatMap(_._2).asJava)})
}
```

I am simply calling this method on a set of these objects to get a `util.Set[util.Map[String], util.Set[String]]`.

```
var unevaluatedacls = for (aclTemplate <- aclTemplates)
  yield aclTemplate.getAcls
```

When I inspect `unevaluatedacls`, I see that it is of the type `HashSet`. But its elements are of the type  `Wrappers$MapWrapper` instead of `util.Map`. As a result of this, I am unable to persist this object. I cannot understand this behavior. When I try

```
var unevaluatedacls = (for (aclTemplate <- aclTemplates)
  yield aclTemplate.getAcls).asJava
```

the `unevaluatedacls` also changes to `Wrapper$SetWrapper`. Is it because I am somehow trying to convert immutable scala collections to java collections? I know that only mutable scala collections are compatible to be converted to corresponding java collections using `JavaConverters`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`JavaConverters` convert containers to/from java "in place", without copying the data. That is, if you have a scala `Map`, and convert it to java, it's not going to create a whole new container, and copy all of the data over to it. Instead, it just returns a wrapper class, that implements the java's `Map` interface, but is backed by the original data rather than a copy.

This is a good thing, because it save both memory and time.

The whole idea of interfaces is that the user is not supposed to care about the particular implementation behind it. "Coding to interface" is the idea. Finding yourself caring about the actual implementation classes is usually (not always, but often) a smell of bad design.

If you have to have your data copied into a container, that's an instance of a particular class, you'll have to do it explicitly:

```
val javaMap = new HashMap[String, Set[String]](wrappedMap)
```

Better yet, consider not using java serialization in the first place. It's slow, buggy, tedious, dangerous ... and forces you jump through million weird hoops like this.  There is a whole lot of better alternatives out there nowadays.

Comment: but basically some of those alternatives are requiring `Serializable` interface as well (let's say memcached)

Comment: @dk14 I am talking about alternatives _to java serialiation_. Like thrift, protobufs, avro, cryo, json etc. No, they do not require serializable interface. 
memcached has nothing to do with this whatsoever.

Comment: I meant that frameworks like spy-memcached (SerializingTranscoder) are falling-back to java serialization if no appropriate transcoder found. Some reflection-based transcoders are requiring `Serializable` as well. I believe (not sure) scala-pickling asks fo `Serializable` (in runtime) when macros can't find appropriate `Decoder` (in compile-time)

Comment: @dk, yes, there are some libs that require Serializable, and there are (lots of) alternative ones that do not. That's exactly what I was saying. :)

Comment: That was my point too. I don't prefer neither reflection nor java-serialization. Something like circe (for json) or scodec (for bytecode if backward compatibility is managed manually) is better for me, but it's not a perfect world, so sometimes you still have to deal with old-buggy-stuff even if you use 3rd party solution, that's all I was saying :) I did +1 the answer already